# Committing a mutation from another module

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I would like to reset the state of my stores upon a logout action. I created mutations in each store to reset the state.

I tried doing something like this with no luck.

```
logout: function ({commit}) {
        commit('resetLoginState')
        commit('menu.resetMenuState')
    }
```

the `logout` function is in my `login` module and the `resetMenuState` is in another module called `menu`

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
commit('path/from/root/to/your/module/menu/resetMenuState', null, { root: true })
```

you can read more about it [on this page](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#accessing-global-assets-in-namespaced-modules)

Comment: Extending upon @David's reply. If your mutation accepts arguments. You can pass them as second argument to the commit like this  `commit('path/from/root/to/your/module/menu/resetMenuState', {id: 2, name: "Anyhting"}, { root: true })`